# openstreet map in android,RunTimeException

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using openstrret map in my android application, I added Hotels in my country to the map using OSM, but when I run my application I get Run time Exception, I don't know what is wrong, and can't find what cause the exception

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
 MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       ////zoom////
        MapController myMapController = mapView.getController();
        myMapController.setZoom(10);

        ScaleBarOverlay myScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myScaleBarOverlay);


        ////zoom////
       Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker) ;
     //   Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

        ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

        myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);



        ExtendedOverlayItem ex=new ExtendedOverlayItem("Funduq Shibbird", "Funduq Shibbird", new GeoPoint(31.4657,35.1347), null);
        ex.setDescription("Funduq Shibbird");
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ex.setImage(icon);
        ex.setMarker(marker);
        final ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadItems = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();
        roadItems.add(ex);
        ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadNodes = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, roadItems, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadNodes);    



        GeoPoint hotel2 = new GeoPoint(31.5522,35.1310);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel2, "Funduq Siti Inn Wahid ", "Funduq Siti Inn Wahid ");

        GeoPoint hotel3 = new GeoPoint(31.5353,35.1238);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel3, "Funduq Siti Inn Ithnayn", "Funduq Siti Inn Ithnayn");

        GeoPoint hotel4 = new GeoPoint(31.4225,35.1155);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel4, "Funduq Shibbird", "Funduq Shibbird");

        GeoPoint hotel5 = new GeoPoint(31.4225,35.1155);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel5, "Funduq al Ayn", "Funduq al Ayn");

        GeoPoint hotel6 = new GeoPoint( 31.3131,34.2623);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel6, "Funduq al Amal", "Funduq al Amal");

        GeoPoint hotel7 = new GeoPoint( 31.3123,342559);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel7, "Funduq Adam", "Funduq Adam");


        GeoPoint hotel8 = new GeoPoint(31.3127,34.262);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel8, "Funfuq Filastin", "Funfuq Filastin");

        GeoPoint hotel9 = new GeoPoint(31.3136,34.2610);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel9, "Cliff Hotel", "Cliff Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel10 = new GeoPoint(31.3139,34.2614);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel10, "Al Quds Hotel", "Al Quds Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel11 = new GeoPoint(31.3132,34.267);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel11, "Beach Hotel", "Beach Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel12 = new GeoPoint(31.4218,35.1217);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel12, "Al Salam Hotel", "Al Salam Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel13 = new GeoPoint(31.4243,35.1212);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel13, "Bethlehem Hotel", "Bethlehem Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel14 = new GeoPoint(32.1315,35.1426);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel14, "Al Qasr Hotel", "Al Qasr Hotel");

        GeoPoint hotel15 = new GeoPoint(31.5344,35.1217);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(hotel15, "Movinpick Hotel", "Movinpick Hotel");


        ///////////////////////////////////
        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        //     mapView.getController().
               } 
           });

       }

   public void List_hotels_ps(View v){


   }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();
     myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
     myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPause();
     myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
     myLocationOverlay.disableFollowLocation();
    }


     //   myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
  //  } 

}
```

and here is the logCat:

```
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.openstreetmap/com.example.openstreetmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class org.osmdroid.views.MapView
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class org.osmdroid.views.MapView
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.example.openstreetmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     ... 11 more
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.osmdroid.views.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.openstreetmap-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.openstreetmap-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
11-10 16:58:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

Comment: Your problem is in line 40 of `InitWindow.java`, in your `InfoWindow` class, which is not part of the source code in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare InfoWindow.java is not of my own classes, I imported osmbonusback.jar in order to use osmdroid

Comment: Ah, you are correct -- my apologies. Which is line 79 of your `MainActivity`?

Comment: @CommonsWare this is line 79:

    ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadNodes = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, roadItems, mapView);

Comment: Hmmmm... I do not quite know what is going wrong. It is fairly deep inside the OSMDroid stuff, as it is inflating the layout for your bubble. Have you done anything with styles/themes that might affect the resources that OSMDroid is trying to use?

Comment: It looks like OSMDroid is not properly attached to your project.

Comment: @CommonsWare how could I make sure of that

Comment: @CommonsWare I get this exception when I add osmbonuspack to my project

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is you have osmdroid.jar at compiling time but not at runtime. This jar is not being loaded in bin directory which is apk's lib directory.

to have load this jar to your apk
right click project->properties->java buildpath->order and export> check osmdroid jar

or

copy and paste osmdroid jar into libs folder then remove it from buildpath(othervise two identical jar will be added to the bin directory, this will cause another problem)